# A link to a paper's url appears twice in a citation

Tags: bibtex, links, elsarticle

When I use the elsarticle-num bibliography style, IF I put an "url={...}" on bibliography, THEN the link to the site of the paper appears twice (one in the name of the paper and one as an URL field on the references section).
However, IF I use a "doi={...}" it only appears once. So my question is: HOW to make a non-DOI reference appear with only ONE link? Below I am attaching a MWE to subsidise your help. Thanks in advance!!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\title{Test Url}

A diverse range of distribution functions have been applied: geometric distributions and hidden Markov models~\cite{melodelima2004modelling}, sum of exponentials and pure Weibull distributions~\cite{gudlaugsdottir2007exon},

 \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num} 
 \bibliography{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

Below I give the bibliography file:

```
@article{melodelima2004modelling,
  title={Modelling the length distribution of exons by sums of geometric laws. Analysis of the structure of genes and G+C influence.},
  author={Melodelima, Christelle and Gu{\'e}guen, Laurent and Piau, Didier and Gautier, Christian},
  journal={Citeseer},
  url={https://core.ac.uk/display/24548251},
  year={2004}
}
@article{gudlaugsdottir2007exon,
  title={Exon size distribution and the origin of introns},
  author={Gudlaugsdottir, Sigurbjorg and Boswell, D Ross and Wood, Graham R and Ma, Jun},
  journal={Genetica},
  doi={10.1007/s10709-007-9139-4},
  volume={131},
  number={3},
  pages={299--306},
  year={2007},
  publisher={Springer}
}
```

It compiles to:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Thanks to Dan MacKinnon for suggestions on improving my question.

Comment: If you expect people to read your article on paper medium, it is better to have the actual URL shown then embedded only as a link from the article title.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Mr. Wong, this is true indeed. But then again, why keep the link on articles's name? I could have the option to keep the link only on the URL field, and not twice, like in the present case.

Comment: Thanks Mrs.  @barbarbeeton !